# Situation of handle after dlclose()/FreeLibrary() fails

Tags: c, winapi, dll, shared-libraries, posix

I'm wrapping the OS dependent API of loading shared libraries at runtime in a portable interface.

The problem is, when documenting the close() function, I noticed that there is no documentation on what happens if the dlclose() or FreeLibrary() function fails. Is the handle still usable, as the library couldn't be closed? Or it is in some corrupted state? Can I still use it?

I need this info to write proper documentation to my API users, and to give some exception guarantee in the C++ interface.

Comment: Call [`GetLastError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360.aspx), report the error, and document the state of the handle as *Unspecified*. There's really not much you can do if cleanup fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you call dlcose the handle is no longer valid for your use:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/dlclose.html

> Once an object has been closed using dlclose() an application should assume that its symbols are no longer available to dlsym().

It is quite possible that `dlclose()` does nothing. Because other libraries also have handles to the library. If the close fails then it usually means somebody else is using it. BUT that does not mean you can use it again via your handle (that is dead).

An error usually indicates your handle is invalid.

Comment: Then, even if dlclose() fails can I assign the handle to NULL? As dlclose() probably won't work anymore...
Can this failure cause any memory leaks?

Comment: Yes set the handle to NULL. Can you do anything about the memory leak? Are there any other calls? Not much you can do once the handle is invalid.

Comment: Thanks. Will go with that.